# 'catalog_category_save_commit_after' this same event is available in magento2?

Tags: magento, events, magento2, observers

I have tried to get the category id to store in my custom table with some values like cat_id, custom_value.

here i googled and get "catalog_category_prepare_save" to get category object when saving the existing category but when adding new order how will i get category id?

*please suggest any events is there in magento2 for "catalog_category_prepare_save"? or suggest to some other method?*

here by add my codes:

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_category_prepare_save">
        <observer name="categoryattributes" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\Categoryattributes"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**Categoryattributes.php**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;

class Categoryattributes implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    private $category = null;
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
         $this->category = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any thing?

Comment: getting category :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used `catalog_category_save_after` event.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_category_save_after">
        <observer name="categoryattributes" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\Categoryattributes"/>
    </event>
  </config>
```

Categoryattributes.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;

class Categoryattributes implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    private $category = null;
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
         $this->category = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use event <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_category_prepare_save">
        <observer name="categoryattributes" instance="Ves\Megamenusync\Observer\Categoryattributes"/>
    </event>
  </config>